# Performance Counters

Tags: .net, performancecounter

using `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter`, I want to write results after every 'x' minutes. Is there any function supported for this or will I have to write some kind of event that gets invoked after every 'x' minutes? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a Timer.